# conditional subquery

Tags: postgresql, optimization, execution-plan, subquery, explain

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id,
   email,
   first_name as "firstName",
   last_name as "lastName",
   is_active as "isActive",
   password,
   access,
   CASE
     WHEN access < 3 THEN (
       SELECT
         CASE WHEN count(*) = 1 THEN true ELSE false END
       FROM user_rating_entity ure
       WHERE ure.user_id = u.id
         AND ure.rating_entity_id = :re_id
     )
     ELSE true
   END as "isResponsible"
FROM users u
WHERE u.id = :id
```

If `access > 3`, field "isResponsible" should be directly set to true and the subquery should not be executed.  I used explain analyze with both cases where access `>=` and `<` to *3* but I get the same output.

Why is that so?

Comment: Never write `then true else false end`. Just write the condition. `select count(*) = 1` ...

Comment: Can you provide sample data or your explain plan for both cases.

Comment: @Evan: That advice happens to apply for the example with `count(*)` which cannot be `null`. But *"never"* is bad advice, it fails for nullable expression, for which the given `CASE` folds `null` to `false`. More elegantly expressed as `COALESCE (<boolean-expression>, false)`.

Comment: Sure, if you want that. `COALESCE` works great. ;) My point was more directed at not writing `then true else false end` seems like an antipattern. Though it's just style.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: But `then true else false end` is *not* just style, it folds `null` to `false`. (Only `count(*)` is never `null` to begin with.)

Comment: Right, I knew that about `count(*)`. I also knew of `coalesce` to fold nulls into false. I'm still unaware of when I would want `then true else false end` as a matter of style (or as a matter of function).

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I added an example to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three important parts to reading query plans here,

- Did it run. If so,
- How many times?
- Was it correlated?

### Sample Data

You didn't provide any sample data, so let's create some.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT x FROM generate_series(1,100) AS x;
```

And, now let's run a basic query with subquery, outside of the possible range of execution.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
  x,
  (CASE WHEN x>200 THEN (SELECT sum(x) FROM foo) END)
FROM foo;
```

The plan will show that the case is accompanied for, but never executed.

```
 Seq Scan on foo  (cost=2.26..4.51 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.047 rows=100 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.25..2.26 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
           ->  Seq Scan on foo foo_1  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4) (never executed)
 Planning time: 0.101 ms
 Execution time: 0.118 ms
(6 rows)
```

You can see that with **(never executed)** on the `Aggregate` line. However, if we set it to something like `CASE WHEN x>20 THEN (SELECT sum(x) FROM foo` you'll see a lot more

```
 Seq Scan on foo  (cost=2.26..4.51 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.020..0.095 rows=100 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.25..2.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Seq Scan on foo foo_1  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.019 rows=100 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.092 ms
 Execution time: 0.158 ms
(6 rows)
```

Here we can see that the Aggregate is looped through `loops=1` time. PostgreSQL realizes that it isn't a correlated subquery and it's a just a reduces it to a literal (essentially). Now let's make sure it's correlated.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
  x,
  (CASE WHEN x>20 THEN (SELECT sum(f2.x)+f1.x FROM foo AS f2) END)
FROM foo AS f1;
```

Now you'll see this plan

```
 Seq Scan on foo f1  (cost=0.00..228.50 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.020..3.210 rows=100 loops=1)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.25..2.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=1 loops=80)
           ->  Seq Scan on foo f2  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.017 rows=100 loops=80)
 Planning time: 0.104 ms
 Execution time: 3.272 ms
```

Here the key is that the aggregate has `loops=80` which itself requires `loops=80` seq scans.

This is all general, but it's all I can give without your sample data, or query plans.

Comment: This is the answer, good explanation I didn't see the never executed (used graphical representation), I upvoted but got less than 15 rep.

Comment: Mark as chosen if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 6):

[Evan already pointed out](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160285/3684) that you may have overlooked the `(never executed)` in the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

A cleaner and more versatile way to write your query in modern Postgres would be with a `LATERAL` subquery (not necessarily faster):

```
SELECT id, email
     , first_name AS "firstName"
     , last_name  AS "lastName"
     , is_active  AS "isActive"
     , password, access
     , COALESCE(ure.resp, true) AS "isResponsible"
FROM  users u
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT (count(*) = 1) AS resp
   FROM   user_rating_entity
   WHERE  user_id = u.id  -- lateral reference
   AND    rating_entity_id = :re_id
   ) ure ON u.access < 3
WHERE  u.id = :id;
```

[Like I commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160281/conditional-subquery#comment307980_160281), [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) is the more elegant replacement for your particular [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) expression.

*But you said `count(*)` is never `null`? Then why `COALESCE()`?*

Even though `count(*)` itself is never `null` (0 for "no rows"), the `LEFT JOIN` still produces `null` where the join condition is no met. And that's the whole point here: Postgres does not count for outer rows where the join condition `u.access < 3` is not met. We get `null` and fold that to `true`, according to your original query.

As we can see in [Evan's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160285/3684), `count(*)` triggers a sequential scan in `user_rating_entity` for every row in `users` that qualifies. OK for small tables or very few users, problematic for big tables.

It can be substantially faster with a matching index to allow index scans:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON user_rating_entity (user_id, rating_entity_id)
```

And if there are more than a few rows per count, there are faster query techniques. But that's stretching the scope of this question ...

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

---

Or:

```
SELECT ...
     , CASE WHEN ure.ct <> 1 THEN false ELSE true END AS "isResponsible"
    -- COALESCE(NOT ure.ct <> 1, true)  -- equivalent
    -- ure.ct = 1                       -- NOT equivalent, misses NULL case
FROM  users u
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
   FROM   ...
   ) ure ON u.access < 3
WHERE  u.id = :id;
```

Same result.

Comment: In your case, shouldn't it be `COALESCE(ure.resp, false) AS "isResponsible"`

Comment: @EvanCarroll: The original query has `else true`in the outer `CASE` expression, so `COALESCE(ure.resp, true)` is the equivalent.